# How to increment a integer value in wrapper class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, inner-class

i have a scenario, i want to increment a value in wrapper class 
let's take  testWrapper class is there , having a Integer variable called incrementX
For ex 5 records are there , 
1st Recorde --> incrementX value should be 0;
2 nd Record --> incrementX value should be 1;
3 rd Record --> incrementX value should be 2;
4 th Record --> incrementX value should be 3;
5 th Record --> incrementX value should be 4

```
public class mainClass{
  public mainClass(){

     for(pse__project_task__c prjTask:lstProjectTask){
        lstwrapperList.add(new validateWrapper(prjTask,subTaskDurationAPJ,subTaskDurationEMEA,subTaskDurationAmericas,mapProjectTaskRegion,R6orR7Tasks,validSkillCheck,mapForState));
        projName=prjTask.pse__project__r.name;

     }
  }

}

public class validateWrapper{
        public pse__project_task__c projectTask{get;set;}
        public Boolean isValidSkill{get;set;}
        public Double  deliveryHoursLimit{get;set;}
        public string skillsTooltip{get;set;}
        public List<pse__project_task__c> projectTaskId=new List<pse__project_task__c>();
        public Boolean isValidstate{get;set;}
        public Integer incrementForList{get;set;}
              //incrementForList=0;

        public validateWrapper(pse__project_task__c task,Double APJ, Double EMEA, Double Americas,map<id,string> mapProjectTaskRegion,map<id,string> R6orR7Tasks,map<id,boolean> validSkillCheck,Map<pse__project_Task__c,boolean> mapValidState){
            isValidSkill=false;
            deliveryHoursLimit=0;
            projectTask=task;
             //incrementForList=0;

            system.debug('incrementForList-->'+task.name+'--'+incrementForList);
            incrementForList++;
            //Check is the task is R6 or R7 and task will have valid Skills
            if(R6orR7Tasks.get(task.id)=='R6'){
                skillsTooltip='At least one skill is mandatory';
                if(validSkillCheck.get(task.id)==true){
                    isValidSkill=true;
                }
            }
            else if(R6orR7Tasks.get(task.id)=='R7'){
                skillsTooltip='At least one service skill and one Support skill is Mandatory';
                if(validSkillCheck.get(task.id)==true){
                    isValidSkill=true;
                }
            }
              //state validation
                isValidstate=mapValidState.get(task);


            //Checing the Region and assigning the delivery estimated hours

            if(mapProjectTaskRegion.get(task.id)==System.Label.GSD_Contract_Reference_APJ){
                deliveryHoursLimit=APJ;
            }
            else if(mapProjectTaskRegion.get(task.id)==System.Label.GSD_Contract_Reference_EMEA){
                deliveryHoursLimit=EMEA;
            }
            else if(mapProjectTaskRegion.get(task.id)==System.Label.GSD_Contract_Reference_AMS){
                deliveryHoursLimit=Americas;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're in a loop when you instantiate your wrappers it should be really easy. But if you don't post code, we can't help you.

Comment: Code Posted .......

Comment: Are you displaying wrapper list on VF page using pageblocktable?

Comment: You should post the code where you are creating list?

Comment: yes rohit , i am using wrapper list in VF page

Comment: @SarathBhusarapu Refer below answers. This can be done in multiple ways as described by Ashwani and myself.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add one more parameter to retain the incremented value. Approach would be as follow:-

```
     Integer countValue = 1 // or any predefined value;
     for(pse__project_task__c prjTask:lstProjectTask){
        lstwrapperList.add(new validateWrapper(prjTask,subTaskDurationAPJ,subTaskDurationEMEA,subTaskDurationAmericas,mapProjectTaskRegion,R6orR7Tasks,validSkillCheck,mapForState,countValue));
        projName=prjTask.pse__project__r.name;
        countValue++; // Or any other logic
     }
```

Wrapper class:-

```
// Added countValue parameter which can be assigned    
public validateWrapper(pse__project_task__c task,Double APJ, Double EMEA, Double Americas,map<id,string> mapProjectTaskRegion,map<id,string> R6orR7Tasks,map<id,boolean> validSkillCheck,Map<pse__project_Task__c,boolean> mapValidState, Integer countValue){
        isValidSkill=false;
        deliveryHoursLimit=0;
        incrementForList = countValue; // new logic
        // ....


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ashwani has suggested one approach, but there is one more way to achieve this by using `apex:variable`.

1. Create a `apex:variable` and use it in a `pageblocktable` or `apex:repeat`.
2. Increment the value of `apex:variable` inside it and display it in `apex:outputText`.

Refer below example:

```
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>

<apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstwrapperList}" var="wrapperItem">

    <apex:column >
        <apex:outputText >
            {!rowNum}
            <apex:variable value="{!rowNum+ 1}" var="rowNum" />
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column >
        <apex:commandLink status="Delete" action="{!selectedRecord }">
            <apex:param name="index" value="{!rowNum}" assignTo="index"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:column>

</apex:pageblockTable>
```

If you want to take any action on a particular record in a page block table then this can also be done by creating a `commandButton` and send `rowNum` as a parameter to `apexMethod()` and get that record from `lstwrapperList`

Example:

```
public Integer index{get;set;}

public void selectedRecord (){
   validateWrapper vwrapper = lstwrapperList.get(index);
}
```